# PHP Simple Echo Code Not Working

Tags: php, html, echo

I've just started to code PHP, I have made a form with a submit button on my HTML page:

```
<form action="thing.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
                E-mail:<br>
            <input type="text" name="mail"><br>
                Comment:<br>
            <input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Send">
            <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

and made a PHP page aswell:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Success</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
  echo "Hello World";
 ?>



</body>

</html>
```

when I click the submit button on the HTML page it shows nothing.

Please help!!

Comment: Is the php file named: "thing.php" ? And where is it stored on the webserver?

Comment: Yes, it is called "thing.php". It is stored in the same file as the HTML file

Comment: `enctype="text/plain"` Look up the correct `enctype` for form data submission. Google is your buddy!

Comment: If you open "thing.php" from the address bar in your browser, do you see "Hello World" ?

Comment: Nope, just nothing

Comment: Do you have a web server installed?

Comment: Download and install WAMP, LAMP or MAMP.

Comment: PHP code will not run unless you have a web server installed with PHP correctly configured. If you are running these files by clicking in explorer then even if ou have a webserver installed it will not run via the web server.